# Converting MM-DD-YYYY varchar to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have 5000+ dates in the following format.

```
00-00-0000
```

And the column data type is varchar. If I change the column type then all my rows are put to 00-00-0000 rather than converting the string literal to a date.

Is it possible to change all 50000+ rows to datetime and also the column data type? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: what is the format ? day-month-year or month-day-year ? there is no time as well, it means all of the datetimes generated from that string will have 00:00 time

Comment: Month-day-year is the format. Hmm, maybe I don't need datetime in that case but only date? I need to use the weekofyear function.

Comment: It should't change data, let me know what procedure you do. The data in the filed should already be in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary `DATE` column and update it using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET temp_date = STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Then drop the varchar date column and rename the temp date column.